# New Users Turned Off and Away

Tags: discussion

[This is not a question, but I've heard that's no problem on Meta. Also, it might be a dupe, but I can't find anything like it.]

One of the things I've noticed on SO is users who come in, answer one or two questions with detailed, expert answers, and get no votes-up whatsoever (because they're not in a popular area, time-of-day) and never come back. I've seen tons of these, but [here's one that I saw today in my touring](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1677066/loading-jruby-classes-from-java-by-class-forname/1713130#1713130).

I think that this is bad and cannot think of any easy ways to solve it aside from voting a good answer up when I see it, even if I don't have time to verify it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On a few occassions I've posted questions about very particular or unusual problems. I've gotten low views, no upvotes, and sometimes only one answer. One correct answer that solved my problem. That's fine by me.

I've certainly also answered obscure questions where the same thing happened. Low views and no votes. (My only pet peeve is when the OP just writes "thanks" and doesn't accept the answer). I guess it would be nice if these answers got lots of upvotes. Oh well. I'm still happy I was able to help someone, and I get paid the same either way.

Answer (score 11):

You're right. Vote a good (*useful and clear*) answer up when you see it.

That's what we're supposed to do.